# Ubuntu wont install properly

Tags: installation, boot

I have successfully burned Ubuntu to a disc but when I go to boot it from the BIOS, I get this error:

```
/casper/vmlinuz: file not found.
```

The installation menu comes up but no matter what option I select, I always get that error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What did you configure as root? Because it looks as is there in an attempt to load the kernel from /casper/vmlinuz. Usuaully this file is stored in either /vmlinuz or in /boot/vmlinuz

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your ISO is corrupted. If you did not already [MD5SUM it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), please do that now.

If it doesn't match, redownload the ISO (and MD5SUM the new one too). If it's good, try burning another disc, as slowly as possible.

<sup>*If that still doesn't work, please add a detailed account of everything you did and what happened, to your question. Please also tell us exactly how you're burning the discs, including what utility you are using.*</sup>